# IAP causing SIGABRT

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

This is my first time working with in app purchases and I'm not sure what it is I am doing wrong. The `SKProductsRequest` Is working perfectly, but when trying to purchase, the app crashes with **SIGABRT**

In **AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  MKStoreObserver *observer = [[MKStoreObserver alloc] init];
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
  return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
  {
    [self requestProductData];
  }
  else {
 }
 [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)buyButton:(id)sender
{
  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:kMyFeatureIdentifier];
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

  //When this button is touched the app crashes
}

- (void)requestProductData
{
   SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]     initWithProductIdentifiers:kMyFeatureIdentifier]];

    request.delegate = self;  
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
 NSArray *myProduct = response.products;

  if (myProduct.count) {

    SKProduct *thisProduct = [myProduct objectAtIndex:0];


    productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thisProduct.localizedTitle];

    productPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"For only $%@", thisProduct.price];

  }
}
```

**MKStoreObserver.m**

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
   for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
   {   

    switch ( transaction.transactionState ) 

    {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: 

            [ self completeTransaction: transaction ];               

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:   

            [ self failedTransaction: transaction ];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:  

            [ self restoreTransaction: transaction ];

            break;

        default:                 

            break;
   }    
  }
}

- (void)completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
 if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
 {
   // Optionally, display an error here.
 }
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

When the buyButton is pressed is when the app crashes

This?

> GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. GDB
>   is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you
>   are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain
>   conditions. Type "show copying" to see the conditions. There is
>   absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin
>
> --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000 target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-4242-20 Switching to remote-macosx protocol mem
>   0x1000 0x3fffffff cache mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none mem 0x00000000
>   0x0fff none [Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03] [Switching to
>   process 7171 thread 0x1c03] sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   2011-12-12 21:39:11.082 inAppTest[171:707] -[__NSCFSet
>   productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134e70
>   2011-12-12 21:39:11.091 inAppTest[171:707] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet
>   productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134e70'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x344298bf 0x346791e5 0x3442cacb 0x3442b945 0x34386680 0x3251b2ed 0x2c9d 0x34383435 0x377ed9eb
>   0x377ed9a7 0x377ed985 0x377ed6f5 0x377ee02d 0x377ec50f 0x377ebf01
>   0x377d24ed 0x377d1d2d 0x30c04df3 0x343fd553 0x343fd4f5 0x343fc343
>   0x3437f4dd 0x3437f3a5 0x30c03fcd 0x37800743 0x2a41 0x29d8) terminate
>   called throwing an exception(gdb)

Comment: But what of the crash logs, my good man?

Comment: what are the crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you define `kMyFeatureIdentifier`? If it has not been defined it seems likely that would lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your crash log, you'll see this line:
-[__NSCFSet productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134e70
This means that an NSSet object of some kind has been asked to supply a value for the property named productIdentifier, which it obviously does not have.

The problem is most likely that the paymentWithProduct: method expects to be handed an SKProduct object. You appear to be giving it an NSSet object. It doesn't notice this until it tries to query what it thinks is an SKProduct for its productIdentifier. I can see that you're using the same constant identifier elsewhere in your code in conjunction with the initWithProductIdentifiers: method, which DOES expect a set. That's probably why you got confused.

I suggest you turn kMyFeatureIdentifier into an actual identifier rather than a set, since that's what its name implies, and then supply initWithProductIdentifiers with [NSSet setWithObject: kMyFeatureIdentifier]